# How to write and read dataframe to parquet where column contains list of dicts

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, pyarrow

I have a column that contain a list of dictionaries and I'm trying to write it to disk using parquet and reading it back into the same original object. However I'm not able to get the same exact object back. Here's the minimal code example to reproduce the issue:

```py
import pyarrow as pa
from pyarrow import parquet
import pandas as pd

COLUMN1_SCHEMA = pa.list_(pa.struct([('Id', pa.string()), ('Age', pa.string())]))
SCHEMA = pa.schema([pa.field("column1", COLUMN1_SCHEMA), ('column2', pa.int32())])

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "column1": [[{"Id": "1"}, {"Age": "16"}], [{"Id": "2"},{"Age": "17"}]],
    "column2": [1, 2],
})

table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df, schema=SCHEMA)
parquet.write_table(table, "f.parquet")

df = pa.parquet.read_table("f.parquet", schema=SCHEMA).to_pandas()
```

The problem is that the dataframe that is read back contains repeating dicts where each value is None (one at a time). Illustration below:

```
                           column1                          column2
0  [{'Id': '1','Age': None}, {'Id': None, 'Age': '16'}]        1
1  [{'Id': '2','Age': None}, {'Id': None, 'Age': '17'}]        2
```

What I wanted was to get the original dataframe back:

```
             column1             column2
0  [{'Id': '1'}, {'Age': '16'}]        1
1  [{'Id': '2'}, {'Age': '17'}]        2
```

Read documentation at pyarrow: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/index.html
Read similar questions at stackoverflow but could not find an answer for this. Also could not find issues on the topic at Pyarrow's github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that the dataframe that is read back contains repeating dicts where each value is None (one at a time).

I'm not sure what your intention is. Do you want individual values to be a dictionary?

If so I'd suggest sending the schema to this (no need for `list_`):

```py
COLUMN1_SCHEMA = pa.struct([('Id', pa.string()), ('Age', pa.string())])
```

And the values to this (no extra `[]` wrapper, everything in the same dict):

```py
[{"Id": "1", "Age": "16"}, {"Id": "2","Age": "17"}]
```

Which gives you

| column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| {'Id': '1', 'Age': '16'} | 1 |
| {'Id': '2', 'Age': '17'} | 2 |

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to reading and writing; the original `table` has the same schema.

```py
In []: table[0].to_pylist()
Out[]: 
[[{'Id': '1', 'Age': None}, {'Id': None, 'Age': '16'}],
 [{'Id': '2', 'Age': None}, {'Id': None, 'Age': '17'}]]
```

The issue is pandas supports arbitrary Python objects, whereas arrow transforms dicts into structs, which have fixed schemas. So the missing fields are padded with nulls.

Relatedly, the example is odd because it has single-value non-overlapping dicts. It seems like the intention was that the data look like:

```py
[{"Id": "1", "Age": "16"}, {"Id": "2", "Age": "17"}]
```

That is, a column of structs, not a column of lists of structs.

Answer (score 0):

A.Coady is correct. The only way to solve this is at the original DataFrame by saving the column as type `str`

```
df["column1"] = df["column1"].astype(str)
```

To convert it back use the Python `ast` package and comprehension

```
df["column1"] = [ast.literal_eval(x) for x in df["column1"].values.tolist()]
```

So your complete code would look like this:

```
import ast
import pyarrow as pa
from pyarrow import parquet
import pandas as pd

SCHEMA = pa.schema([pa.field("column1", pa.string()), ('column2', pa.int32())])

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "column1": [[{"Id": "1"}, {"Age": "16"}], [{"Id": "2"},{"Age": "17"}]],
    "column2": [1, 2],
})
df["column1"] = df["column1"].astype(str)
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df, schema=SCHEMA)
parquet.write_table(table, "f.parquet")

df = pa.parquet.read_table("f.parquet", schema=SCHEMA).to_pandas()
df["column1"] = [ast.literal_eval(x) for x in df["column1"].values.tolist()]
df
```